# ffmpeg command working from command line but not in bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, ffmpeg

I am converting wav files to mp3 files using ffmpeg. The conversion works when I run it from the command line but it doesn't work when it is run from a bash script. The error I get is a ffmpeg error
here is the command that i'm running from the command line (successfully) and from the bash script (unsuccessfully):

```
ffmpeg -i /home/fn/audio/Example\ Folder/6058255.wav -acodec mp3 /home/fn/audio/Example\ Folder/6058255.mp3
```

Here is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/home/fn/audio"
WAV_EXT="wav"
inotifywait -m -r --format '%w%f' -e create "$DIR" | while read -r FILE
do
if [[ "$FILE" == *"$WAV_EXT"* ]] ; then
    MP3_FILE="$(echo -e "${FILE}" | sed 's/wav/mp3/')"
    ffmpeg -nostdin -i "$FILE" -acodec mp3 "$MP3_FILE"
fi
done
```

Here is the error/ouput i am getting:

```
    ffmpeg version 4.2.2-0york0~16.04 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='0york0~16.04' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
/home/fn/audio/Example Folder/6058255.wav: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: What is the `ffmpeg` error? Please show your bash script.

Comment: Sorry about that. It has been added now. @llogan

Comment: What happens if you rename your Example Folder to Example_Folder (try with replacing the blank in the folder name).

Comment: same experience i'm having right now

Answer (score 2):

Add the `-nostdin` global option to `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -i "$input" "$output"
```

This will keep `ffmpeg` from interfering with the stdin for the `read` statement and keeping the loop from working properly. This is the main problem.

You can simplify the script with [parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073):

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/home/fn/audio"
inotifywait -m -r --format '%w%f' -e create "$DIR" | while read -r FILE
do
    ffmpeg -nostdin -i "$FILE" "${FILE%.*}.mp3"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I made the changes, but am still getting the same error unfortunately. I don't know what could be causing the issue. I tried with using the external decoder -> libgsm_ms but again got the same error. So I don't know what the issue could be. @llogan

Comment: @MitchellJ Please edit your question to include the new bash script you used and the complete output it gives you in the terminal.

Comment: I edited the questions and the error. @llogan

Comment: @MitchellJ Can you provide a link to `6058255.wav`?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't make the recording public.

Comment: @MitchellJ Not much else I can suggest without a sample file, but I simplified the script regardless.

Comment: No worries thank for all the help.